# Recursion JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript

```
const sequenceSum = (begin, end) => {
  // BEGIN (write your solution here)
  if (begin === end) {
    return end;
  } else if (begin > end) {
    return NaN;
  }

  return end + sequenceSum(end-1);
  // END
};

export default sequenceSum;
```

Hello. I don't the understand problem with the above code. I've got the following error:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Looks like the recursion never stops. How exactly, i.e. with what arguments, do you call that function?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not provide second parameter to function call at `return end + sequenceSum(end-1)` resulting in neither `if` nor `if..else` statement  being reached, as `end` is not defined; instead `return end + sequenceSum(end-1)` is called repeatedly.

Comment: Yea, thank you! return end + sequenceSum(begin, end-1); :)